# Search function with Greek characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, function, search, unicode

I have a search function for old Greek words ([Wearch.nl](http://wearch.nl)).
The old greek words have mutch accents, ῦ is not the same as ὐ, but I want that if you type a "u" you get the results for ῦ and ὐ (and the other 5 variations). I am using the LIKE function of MySQL to get the results. 
I could search for all of them but I hope it can be shorter and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to change the character set of your column (or table) then set it to `utf8_general_ci` ([link to manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8_general_ci;
```

With this character set (which is case insensitive, as denoted by `_ci`), accented characters have the same weight (the value used for [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-general.html)), so they return true when compared with each other ([link to manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-implementations.html)):

> Non-UCA collations have a one-to-one
>   mapping from character code to weight.
>   In MySQL, such collations are case
>   insensitive and accent insensitive.
>   utf8_general_ci is an example: 'a',
>   'A', 'À', and 'á' each have different
>   character codes but all have a weight
>   of 0x0041 and compare as equal.

```
mysql> SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'A', 'a' = 'À', 'a' = 'á';
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 'a' = 'A' | 'a' = 'À' | 'a' = 'á' |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         1 |         1 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

Alternatively, or if you cannot alter the database configuration in this way, you could write a function to replace accented characters with their non-accented equivalents (i.e. `é` -> `e`) and write this into a dedicated search field (a [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) field is recommended). Perform searches on this field and return the accented field to the application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have done your instructions, I've set the character set to utf8_general_ci. 
When I run a query on the server with the LIKE function:
`SELECT * FROM  grieks WHERE gr LIKE  "%ε%" LIMIT 0 , 30`
It Selects all the ε forms (ε,ἔ,έ etc.). But when I do this from PHP it doesn't work.
I use 
`mysql_connect("localhost","deb*****_******","[password]"); mysql_select_db("deb*****_******") or die( "Unable to select database");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");`
To connect to my database. 
Do I have to change something in the conect method?

Comment: If I do not use 
`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");`
I only get questions marks, no greek characters.

Comment: Try this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php and check the comments for gotchas :)