# How to add japanese characters into mysql database through jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-rds

Whenever I try to add any japanese characters to the mysql database through jdbc, the characters are converted to question marks. I want to add those actual japanese characters. How can I do so?


There are similar questions on stackoverflow but none addresses the same issue as this.

PS. The mysql database is an AWS RDS database.

Comment: Are you using the `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding` parameters in your connection string? (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19635942/2144390) for details.)

Comment: This is awesome!! It did the trick. I had tried the same thing. But I had declared the DB_URL inside a config file and it was failing. Thanks as it works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has more to do with the encoding of your database than your actual SQL client. Your database should be configured to use an encoding that will allow Japanese characters. UTF-8 is recommended.

Specifying the encoding of your database is usually done during DB set-up time, not with your (Java) code. As you mentioned that you are using Amazon RDS I'm not sure what specific steps you should take. However, I usually do this per table on my MySQL set-ups. [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html) for the particular MySQL documentation.

Additionally, it may be that the Japanese characters are getting inserted fine but your viewing client (terminal, browser, etc.) is not configured to the proper encoding.

Comment: Java has the tendency to convert untranslatable characters (those that don't have a mapping in the target encoding) to question marks; I'd wager there's some misconfiguration there.

Comment: Thanks but how can I specify the encoding? <br> Currently I am using DB_URL = jdbc:mysql://URL_HIDDEN/TABLE_NAME; <br>How to make it use utf8?

Comment: @skytreader I have run the sql command "ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;";. But still the characters cant be added to the database.